# dbt / jinja: Add coalesce to every column coming from dbt_utils.get_filtered_columns_in_relation macro by loop

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I am trying to make use of a loop to add the coalesce function to every column that is delivered by the dbt_utils.get_filtered_columns_in_relation macro (see picture attached). I am following the example mentioned in the docs (https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils/tree/0.9.2/#get_filtered_columns_in_relation-source), but I am still getting errors like

```
001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
13:54:48    syntax error line 27 at position 2 unexpected '"ARTICLE_REFERENCE_GROUP"'.
13:54:48    syntax error line 39 at position 2 unexpected 'from'.
13:54:48    syntax error line 51 at position 0 unexpected ')'.
```

It seems to me that there is still something wrong regarding the quotes or similar.If I add additional single quotes to the column alias, I am getting

```
14:21:39    syntax error line 13 at position 36 unexpected ''COMPANY_NR''.
14:21:39    syntax error line 14 at position 49 unexpected ''ARTICLE_REFERENCE_GROUP''.
```

etc.

Do you have experience with this/jinja/loops and can support me fixing it? Thanks in advance!

My current code:

```
with source as (

  {% set coalescecols = adapter.get_columns_in_relation(from=source('stg_poc_dbt','prices'), except=['_business_dt','_country_cd','_input_filename','_row_nr','_dq_st','_dq_err_msg','_run_id','_batch_id']) %}

  select 
    {% for col in coalescecols %}
        coalesce({{ col.name }}, '') as {{ col.name }}
        {%- if not loop.last %},{% endif -%}
    {% endfor %}
    --{{ dbt_utils.star(from=source('stg_poc_dbt','prices'), except=['_business_dt','_country_cd','_input_filename','_row_nr','_dq_st','_dq_err_msg','_run_id','_batch_id'])}}
  from 
    {{ source('stg_poc_dbt','prices') }}
```

Comment: It looks like quotes are going into the generated SQL. Have you tested what you're trying to do outside/in raw SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually with the line you tried to comment out!

Jinja is templated first, and then the SQL is passed to your database. This line:

```sql
--{{ dbt_utils.star(from=source('stg_poc_dbt','prices'), except=['_business_dt','_country_cd','_input_filename','_row_nr','_dq_st','_dq_err_msg','_run_id','_batch_id'])}}
```

will get compiled into a list of column names that are on different lines, so the sql comment `--` will only remove the first of those column names.

Jinja comments take the form `{# ... #}` so if you want to comment out your call to `star`, you need to do this:

```sql
{# {{ dbt_utils.star(from=source('stg_poc_dbt','prices'), except=['_business_dt','_country_cd','_input_filename','_row_nr','_dq_st','_dq_err_msg','_run_id','_batch_id'])}} #}
```

More generally, the best way to debug jinja is to look at the *compiled* code. You can find that in the `target/compiled` directory in your project, after you execute `dbt run`, `dbt build`, or `dbt compiled`. That will show you the SQL that is generated after the jinja is templated, and you would have seen the issue in that compiled code.

Comment: Many thanks for your response and hints! I deleted that row and the code works as expected, at least for "materialized = 'table'". I am facing another issue when running it with incremental and thats why the target/compiled code just shows the merge statement (unfortunately not the whole sql code). But that's another topic - thanks again!